# How to get results out of yield and save to file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, scrapy

I am practicing to use the Scrapy webcrawler package and have a 2 part question because I am struggling a little bit to know what to do next:

1. I have a script called `spider4Techcrunch.py` which contains the following code:

   ```
   import scrapy
   from scrapy import cmdline

   class TCSpider(scrapy.Spider):
       name = "techcrunch"

       def start_requests(self):
           urls = [
               "https://techcrunch.com/"
           ]

           for url in urls:
               yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse)

       def parse(self, response):
           SET_SELECTOR = ".post-block__title"
           output = "--BEGIN OUTPUT--"
           print(output)
           for data in response.css(SET_SELECTOR):
               print('--BEGIN DATA--')
               print(data)
               TITLE_SELECTOR = "a ::text"
               URL_SELECTOR = "a ::attr(href)"
               yield {
                   'title': data.css(TITLE_SELECTOR).extract_first(),
                   'url':data.css(URL_SELECTOR).extract_first(),
               }


   scrapy.cmdline.execute("scrapy runspider spider4Techcrunch.py".split())
   ```

   When I execute the code, everything is working perfectly and returning results. Where I am struggling is with the `yield` command. How do I extract the text results of the `KEY: VALUE` pairs for `"title": "url"` from the `yield` command so that I can save the results into a text file line by line?
2. The last line in my code, is this a proper way to execute it? It just looks weird to me that I am executing the scrapy code by calling itself within the same file. **Is there a best practice/better way? (Keeping in mind, I would like this class to be reusable for multiple URLS.)**

   ```
   scrapy.cmdline.execute("scrapy runspider spider4Techcrunch.py".split())
   ```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Preferred way to run scrapy application as script - [docs](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/practices.html#run-scrapy-from-a-script) 
You can use one of built-in [feed exporters](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/feed-exports.html)  
In your case it solution will be like this (for scrapy version 2.1):

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess

    class TCSpider(scrapy.Spider):
        name = "techcrunch"

        def start_requests(self):
            urls = [
                "https://techcrunch.com/"
            ]

            for url in urls:
                yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse)

        def parse(self, response):
            SET_SELECTOR = ".post-block__title"
            output = "--BEGIN OUTPUT--"
            print(output)
            for data in response.css(SET_SELECTOR):
                print('--BEGIN DATA--')
                print(data)
                TITLE_SELECTOR = "a ::text"
                URL_SELECTOR = "a ::attr(href)"
                yield {
                    'title': data.css(TITLE_SELECTOR).extract_first(),
                    'url':data.css(URL_SELECTOR).extract_first(),
                }

    process = CrawlerProcess(settings={
        "FEEDS": {
            "items.json": {"format": "json"},
            #"items.jl": {"format": "jsonlines"},

        },
    })

process.crawl(TCSpider)
process.start()
```

Comment: Just tested this. Absolutely beautiful. Thanks @Georgiy for your help!

Comment: @Georgiy . Question though, if you don't mind.  Aside from saving it to json or csv file, how do store the result out of yield into a global variable? I'm very new to scrappy.

Comment: @Georgiy you can do something like this after the crawler has finished crawling
```results = None```
```with open("output_file.json", "r") as f:
    results = json.load(f)```

Answer (score 1):

Adding to your way of executing the script:

Instead of calling the command `scrapy runspider spider4Techcrunch.py`,
add the parameter of `-O items.json`.

i.e. `scrapy runspider spider4Techcrunch.py -O items.json` will save all the yield items into a JSON file.

It will give similar output as suggested in @Georgiy's answer.

If you want to call from the command line, a more concise way is `scrapy crawl <name-of-spider> -O items.json` from your scrapy project directory.

In this case, it would be `scrapy crawl techcrunch -O item.json`

Answer (score 0):

You can save result from yield by using item pipelines

step1) you have to write item pipelines like this

```
class PricePipeline:
    vat_factor = 1.15

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        if item.get('price'):
            if item.get('price_excludes_vat'):
                item['price'] = item['price'] * self.vat_factor
            return item
        else:
            raise DropItem("Missing price in %s" % item)
```

step2) you have to modify your settings.py

```
ITEM_PIPELINES = {
    'your.pipelines.class': 300,
}
```

refere https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/item-pipeline.html for more detail